# avoid SonarQube null assignment rule

Tags: java, performance, validation, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm fixing some code bugs, it is an old code, and when i run sonar to get all validations says

Assigning an Object to null is a code smell. Consider refactoring.

Code looks like that

```
public Module getModule(final String moduleType) {
        Module module = null;
if (Utils.executeIsNullOrEmptyS(moduleType)) {
            module = null;
        } else {
//Lines of code
        }
}
}
```

There I got PMD rule notification:

[image]

How can I avoid this PMD rule, I mean try not to asign null to a module or declare a new empty module, which is better?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public Module getModule(final String moduleType) {
    Module module = null;
    if (!Utils.executeIsNullOrEmptyS(moduleType)) {
      //Lines of code
    }
}
```

Basically remove the condition where you set it again to null.